# Create a widget to embed into QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have this task that I couldn't solve yet. Working with PyQt and Qt Creator.

I want to embed a custom created widget created in QT Creator into another QMainWindow.

1) Steps I do:

Create a Widget file in QT creator:

[image]

2) Save it as *.ui and apply this line to convert it to a *.py file:

```
pyuic5 gen_settings.ui -o gen_settings.py
```

3) Open it and see that it starts with

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_gen_settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, gen_settings):
        gen_settings.setObjectName("gen_settings")
```

4) Which results in function call of course:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'function'
```

when I call it in another QMainWindow file:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, My_Custom_widget):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(My_Custom_widget, 1, 4, 1, 1)
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I recommend you read [the PyQt docs referring to Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Going to the problem, Qt Designer does not provide a widget but a class that serves as an interface to a widget, and that can be seen in his statement:

```
class Ui_gen_settings(object):
    # ...
```

The class inherits from object and not from QWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow, etc.

In the docs that indicate initially it is recommended to create a widget and use the interface provided by Qt Designer. For this it is correct to use pyuic but I will change the gen_settings.py to gen_settings_ui.py so that the change is understood.

```
pyuic5 gen_settings.ui -o gen_settings_ui.py
```

So now we create a file called gen_settings.py that contains the widget and use the interface.

**gen_settings.py**

```
from gen_settings_ui import Ui_gen_settings
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Gen_Settings(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_gen_settings):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gen_Settings, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

---

Then when you create the .ui corresponding to Ui_MainWindow you add a QWidget that is an empty container.

[image]

[image]

In the image, the Widget container is the one in the upper left, and now we will replace it with Gen_Settings, so we must [promote](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) it using the following procedure:

1. Right click on the widget container and select the `Promote To ...` option.

[image]

2. The following Dialog will appear and fill in the fields as shown in the image (I'm assuming that gen_settings_ui.py and gen_settings.py are in the same folder as the current .ui)

[image]

3. You press the Add button and then the Promote button.

---

Then you convert the .ui to .py with pyuic and you will get the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        # ...
        self.widget = Gen_Settings(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        # ...

from gen_settings import Gen_Settings
```

Comment: thanks very much. It all worked. That way can I make this QWidget changeable? My idea is to have a step-by-step pipeline GUI where at each particular time I want to change this QWidget with another one depending on the state of pipeline. I was looking for some good examples how to design it in a smart way, but didn't find any for PyQt or Qt itself. Maybe I'm completely on a wrong track..